# How is relative interaction energy defined and quantified?

Tags: energy, terminology, intermolecular-forces, statistical-mechanics

I understand the interaction energy is the energy associated or caused by the interaction between the objects. So, for atoms it has to be the sum of van der Waals interaction and Coulomb interaction.

If there are a bunch of atoms in the system, what does the term *relative interaction energy* mean? How to conceptually understand this term, and how do we measure or calculate it?

Comment: See also [wikipedia.org Interaction_energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_energy)

Comment: Yeah, I have already looked into it. But, I confusion is regarding conceptually understanding it, and the term relative.

Comment: It was meant rather just as a general additional reference, as  you should provide in the question the explicit compact result of your preliminary effort before asking. You should e.g. provide the context using the term "relative interaction energy".

Comment: Based on the general concept "relative X = absolute X / absolute X0", the contextless guess says that relative interaction energy is ratio of 2 interaction energy values, e.g. during comparison of 2 related cases.